# Laravel Eloquent Convert user_id to user info

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've some relationships in my Model classes.

---

Consume this relationship:
We've `Post()` model which store our posts data. Each post in this table has a `user_id` column that has one to many relationship with `User()` Mode (the author of the post)

```
class User extends Model {
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
}
```

```
class Post extends Model {

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

So when i want to return my post with elequent, I'll get something like this:

```
{
    "user_id": 1,
    "title": "Foo name",
    "body": "Foo body",
},
{
    "user_id": 1,
    "title": "Bar name",
    "body": "another Bar body",
}
```

But i want to get something like this:

```
{
    "user_id": 1,
    "user": {
        'name'=> 'John',
        'last'=> 'Maco',
     },
    "title": "Foo name",
    "body": "Foo body",
},
{
    "user_id": 1,
    "user": {
        'name'=> 'John',
        'last'=> 'Maco',
     },
    "title": "Bar name",
    "body": "another Bar body",
}
```

Comment: Something like: `Post::with('user')->get()` should work. see here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: @dparoli Thanks you, It's all of what i want

Comment: You're welcome, your relationships have already the right naming convention so the query is easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the relation from `Post` to `User`

`Post.php`

```php
class Post extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Then you will be able to load the user with every post like @dparoli commented

```php
$post = Post::with('user')->get();
```